# Transformar objetos str Pandas em valores numericos

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Como faço em Python para transformar a seguinte cadeia de caracteres:

`[[98 9] [55 16] [9 50] [68 0] [24 1] [80 16]]`

em duas cadeia de vetores numéricos (a primeira cadeia contendo os primeiros valores:

`98 55 9 ...`

e o segundo vetor contendo os segundo valores:

`9, 16, 50 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Essa "cadeia de caracteres" que se refere, na verdade é uma lista de listas, ou pode ser interpretado como uma matriz também, para fazer o que pede, basta percorrer a lista, e atribuir todo valor no indice '0' de cada item, em uma lista, e do índice '1' em outra, da seguinte forma:

```
lista = [[98, 9], [55, 16], [9, 50], [68, 0], [24, 1], [80, 16]]
a = [] 
b = [] 
for i in lista:
        a.append(i[0])
        b.append(i[1]) 
print(a,'/',b)
```

A saída será:

> [98, 55, 9, 68, 24, 80] / [9, 16, 50, 0, 1, 16]

Comment: Muito obrigado Absolver, mas ainda não estou conseguindo... quando eu dou um `print(type(lista)` está parecendo a seguinte mensagem: `<class 'str'>` talvez eu tenha que fazer alguma conversão antes para aplicar esta solução. Caso você possa me ajudar nesta conversão, ficaria muito grato. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Provavelmente existe uma forma de gerar esse output em formato de lista, ou matriz, contudo se quer transformar exatamente do jeito que está em listas separadas, trabalhe com list(string.split(" ")) , assim você particiona a lista utilizando uma chave, no caso uma vírgula ou espaços.